# Running couenne from pyomo within Jupyter notebook

Tags: pyomo

I am trying to run Couenne within pyomo framework in a Jupyter notebook. When I try to run a problem via pyomo within notebook, I get the following:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

# create a model
model = ConcreteModel()

# declare decision variables
model.x = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.y = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)

# declare objective
model.profit = Objective(expr = 40*model.x + 30*model.y, sense=maximize)

# declare constraints
model.demand = Constraint(expr = model.x <= 40)
model.laborA = Constraint(expr = model.x + model.y <= 80)
model.laborB = Constraint(expr = 2*model.x + model.y <= 100)

model.pprint()

def display_solution(model):

    # display solution
    print('\nProfit = ', model.profit())

    print('\nDecision Variables')
    print('x = ', model.x.value)
    print('y = ', model.y())

    print('\nConstraints')
    print('Demand  = ', model.demand())
    print('Labor A = ', model.laborA())
    print('Labor B = ', model.laborB())

opt = SolverFactory("couenne") 
opt.options['display_stats']= 'yes'
res = opt.solve(model, tee=True)
```

Exception in thread Thread-19:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "c:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\threading.py", line 917, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "c:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\subprocess.py", line 1495, in _readerthread
buffer.append(fh.read())
File "c:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 38: invalid start byte
2 Var Declarations
x : Size=1, Index=None
Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
None :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
y : Size=1, Index=None
Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
None :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

1 Objective Declarations
profit : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
None :   True : maximize : 40*x + 30*y

3 Constraint Declarations
demand : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
Key  : Lower : Body : Upper : Active
None :  -Inf :    x :  40.0 :   True
laborA : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
Key  : Lower : Body  : Upper : Active
None :  -Inf : x + y :  80.0 :   True
laborB : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
Key  : Lower : Body    : Upper : Active
None :  -Inf : 2*x + y : 100.0 :   True

6 Declarations: x y profit demand laborA laborB

I'm using pyomo 6.6.2, in a python 3.9 venv.

I can successfully do following within the notebook, and it spits out the correct answer:

```
import sys
!couenne .\circle.nl
```

which indicates couenne is correctly installed, at least for command-line operation.
Other solvers such as CBC, IPOPT etc. work fine with the Jupyter notebook.

Running directly from a .py script from command line gives similar output:

C:/Users/paulx/anaconda3/envs/python39env/python.exe c:/Users/paulx/OneDrive/Documents/Technical_Projects/Python/VacuumPump/couenneExample.py
2 Var Declarations
x : Size=1, Index=None
Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
None :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
y : Size=1, Index=None
Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
None :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

1 Objective Declarations
profit : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
None :   True : maximize : 40*x + 30*y

3 Constraint Declarations
demand : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
Key  : Lower : Body : Upper : Active
None :  -Inf :    x :  40.0 :   True
laborA : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
Key  : Lower : Body  : Upper : Active
None :  -Inf : x + y :  80.0 :   True
laborB : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
Key  : Lower : Body    : Upper : Active
None :  -Inf : 2*x + y : 100.0 :   True

6 Declarations: x y profit demand laborA laborB
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\threading.py", line 917, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\subprocess.py", line 1495, in _readerthread
buffer.append(fh.read())
File "C:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 38: character maps to Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\paulx\OneDrive\Documents\Technical_Projects\Python\VacuumPump\couenneExample.py", line 36, in 
res = opt.solve(model, tee=True)
File "C:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 533, in solve
self.available(exception_flag=True)
File "C:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\ASL.py", line 119, in available
return self.version() is not None
File "C:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 436, in version
self._version = self._get_version()
File "C:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\ASL.py", line 105, in _get_version
ver = _extract_version(results.stdout)
File "C:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 44, in _extract_version
m = re.search('[t,T]runk', x)
File "C:\Users\paulx\anaconda3\envs\python39env\lib\re.py", line 201, in search
return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: yes, I tried a direct script also, but gives similar output (original question updated to reflect that).

Comment: Preferably the title would be changed since your script does the same things without Jupyter involved.